# Rails ActiveStorage memory leak/bloating issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

First of all, keep in mind that I'm new to Ruby and Rails.

I'm getting a memory leak/bloating issue when using Rails ActiveStorage.

I'm trying to stream a large file (~1GB) stored Using ActiveStorage using a controller method. I don't want to expose a direct connection to the storage service so I'm trying to stream the file through an application controller.

And it works fine, the only problem is that every time I download a file the memory of the application increases by about the file size and is not collected by the GC.

I know that Ruby does not release the memory back to the os, but it seems that it does not even get garbage collected. Event when manually triggering the GC using GC.start method.

I've even created a controller that exposes some GC functions to look at the stats and trigger GC manually, but that does not help.

This is the method that streams the file

```
def content
  file = CloudFile.find_by(id: params[:id])

  if file && file.content && file.content.attached?
    send_blob_stream file.content
  else
    head :not_found
  end
end
```

Here is what I'm trying:

1. Start the server
   Initial memory:
   [image: initial memory usage]
2. Download ~1GB file
   Memory usage:
   [image]
3. Trigger GC by calling POST /api/gc/start
4. Download ~1GB file
   Memory usage:
   [image]

Why does the memory keep increasing and not get GC? Shouldn't the memory usage plateau? In my testing, it does not plateau but continues to increase with every download.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you think it's a memory leak and not legitimate memory usage? What's in `file.content`? When you stream data the memory usage should not increase significantly in the first place. It looks like your application is loading the whole content of the file into the memory.

Comment: I suggest reconsidering your decision to pass the file through your application. That might not only cause memory issues (as you already noticed) but also makes your application vulnerable to deal of service attacks (even by accident). Because the server process will be blocked and cannot be used for other connections for the whole time it takes to download the file. Several downloads to your app at the same time and the app like not able to respond to other requests anymore. I suggest direct downloads from the cloud with signed URLs that are only valid for a very short time (just seconds).

Comment: @DieterPisarewski `file.content` is the attachment. I also expected that `send_blob_stream` would not load the file in memory, but it seems like it does...

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for your response! I'll reconsider it.

Comment: @Peter `send_blob_stream` doesn't load it into memory. It is probably done somewhere else in your application. https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Streaming.html#method-i-send_blob_stream

Comment: @Peter it also might be the response object which buffers the whole response body before sending to the client.

Comment: @DieterPisarewski By the 'response object' do you mean the 'response' from this method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a2fc96a80cf26c11df3e86e86c1b2b61736af80c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb#L321?

Comment: I mean any response object which is allocated inside your application process, eg. in action controller or rack middleware.